# Maven 3: Assembling a Jar file containing binary resources

Tags: maven, assemblies, maven-3

I have setup a Maven project consisting of two child modules, one Java Jar module and one creating a Windows Executable using NPanday. My build is working great.

The problem I am having, is that I would like to create a Jar file containing my Java lib and have the Exe file embedded so I can load it as a resource from the code inside the lib.

It seems the assembly plugin would be the path to go, but I am having some trouble configuring this. I don't even know if this is the correct path to go in this case.

Could someone here please guide me to the right path or give me a hint as to how such an assembly descriptor should look like?

Chris

Comment: Yes, assembly plugin should be ok. Can you show what would you like the contents of jar file to be?

Comment: I'll answer your question in a main "answer" cause SO keept on messing up my linebreaks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... so it seems I sorted out a solution on my own. I know this question was relatively special again ... as all of my questions seem to be :-)

The solution was to create a maven module containing a custom implementation of a PlexusIoResourceCollection and to reference this from a components.xml file in the "META-INF/plexus" directory.

After adding this as a dependency to my assembly plugin, I was able to embed the exe files into my jar :-)

Here comes the code of the component:

```
package npanday.plugin.archiver;

import org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoCompressedFileResourceCollection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: cdutz
 * Date: 02.03.12
 * Time: 12:04
 */
public class PlexusIoExeResourceCollection extends PlexusIoCompressedFileResourceCollection {

    @Override
    protected String getDefaultExtension() {
        return ".exe";
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getInputStream(File file) throws IOException {
        // Simply return an InputStream to the resource file.
        // This will make it embed the source as a whole.
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        // Without overriding this, the exe would be included with its full path.
        // This way it is included directly in the root of the result archive.
        return super.getFile().getName();
    }

}
```

Here the config xml in META-INF/plexus/components.xml

```
<component-set>
    <components>
        <component>
              <role>org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoResourceCollection</role>
              <role-hint>exe</role-hint>
              <implementation>npanday.plugin.archiver.PlexusIoExeResourceCollection</implementation>
              <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
            </component>
    </components>
</component-set>
```

And finally the usage in my assembly plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.npanday.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-exe-archiver-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${npanday.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Hopefully it will do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a Java Project, that only contains a test Class for now, as I am still in the stage of setting up my build:

Module de.cware.utils:lib-psexec-client:

- /de/cware/utils/psexec/client/Test.java

Module de.cware.utils:lib-psexec-service:
outputs a file called "service.exe"

I want the output to look like the client jar, but to also contain the "service.exe" so I can load it from the code in the Client jar.

Module de.cware.utis:lib-psexec-assembly:

- /de/cware/utils/psexec/client/Test.java
- /service.exe

Comment: Well I actually managed to solve my problem: The solution was to implement a custom PlexusIoResourceCollection and to reference that as a dependency in the assembly plugin.